# How to truncate/slice strings on Django Template Engine?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

index.html

```
<td>{% if place or other_place or place_description%}{{ place}} {{ other_place}} {{place_description}}</td>
```

This is displaying all the data in template.I want to truncate the string if it is more than length 80.

Conditions are,
1.If place variable have more than 80 character,it should truncate their and need not show the other two variable like other_place and place_description.

2.If place variable and other_place variable making more than 80 character,in this case it should truncate from place_variable don't need to show place_description variable.

3.If all the three are their and the 80th character is made from place_description,need to truncate from their.

All fields are not mandatory,so whatever field is comes to display,it should show only 80 character.

Need help to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) for pre-django 1.4:

```
{% if place or other_place or place_description%}
    {% with place|add:other_place|add:place_description as pl %}
        {% if pl|length > 80 %}
            {{pl|slice:80}}...
        {% else  %}
            {{pl }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

If you are using django 1.4 or greater,

You can just use [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

```
{% if place or other_place or place_description%}
    {% with place|add:other_place|add:place_description as pl %}
       {{pl|truncatechars:80}}
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I would use the `{{ value|truncatechars:80 }}` template filter instead of slice as it adds the elipsis as well denoting the string as truncated

Comment: Ah, sorry for that! Carry on then! :)

Comment: @karthikr,i can't use truncatechars,which is not supported in django 1.3

Comment: I am getting this templatesyntax error "Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: It could be elsewhere in the code. You dont get this error if you remove this snippet ?

Comment: May be,let me check first.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably do it with a combination of add/truncatechars e.g.

```
{{ place|add:other_place|add:place_description|truncatechars:80}}
```

Comment: I am using django 1.3,this may applicable >django 1.4

Comment: ah ok, you could create your own filter based on the django one e.g. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L254

Answer (score 3):

You could also use 'cut' which is part of django template builtins

for example if

```
{{ file.pdf.name}}
```

gives 'store/pdfs/verma2010.pdf'

```
{{ file.pdf.name | cut:'store/pdfs/'}}
```

Would give  'verma2010.pdf'

Answer (score 1):

Took me way too long to find the answer in 2022. It's `truncatechars`, e.g.

```
{{ my_string|truncatechars:1 }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars