# Django slice string in template doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to slice my string but it doesn't work. It works perfectly on other variables but with this one it does nothing.

```
{{b.rec_company|slice:":2"}}
```

Comment: Check b.rec_company type is it string or not,

Comment: How can i check this in template?

Comment: This field is foreign field in my model.

Comment: Can you display your model structure in question.

Answer (score 1):

You use slice for pre-django 1.4:

```
{{b.rec_company|slice:'2'}}

{{ b.rec_company|slice:":-3" }}
```

If you are using django 1.4 or greater,

You can just use truncatechars

```
{{b.rec_company|truncatechars:2}}
```

For more reference use [slice-string-in-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596141/django-slice-string-in-template)

Comment: i'm using django 1.8 but truncate doesn't slice string, it replace chars with dots.

Comment: Can you please mention error and expected output in question.

Comment: TEST COMP and i want that my output wille be only T. There is no error it does nothing it displays name as it is in database

Comment: ``{{'someSting'|slice:":2"}}`` this is working on my side.